# How to display celery output on the frontend?

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a celery task in my project that trigger a command from another project.
Everything is working well. I'm running the celery command as

```
celery -A fdaconfig worker --loglevel=info
```

How can I display the outputs of terminal in the frontend?

```
@shared_task
def trigger_model(main_config, runmode_config, modelreport):
    with cd("/another_project"):
        spark_submit_str = "python3 run_trigger.py " + "/this_project" + main_config

        process = subprocess.Popen(spark_submit_str, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                   universal_newlines=True, shell=True)

        stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
        if process.returncode != 0:
            print(stderr)
        print(stdout)
```

Comment: I would try writing the celery logs to a file and then reading from that file on the frontend. I can't say precisely how to read the file because you have not specified any details about your frontend. For information on how to redirect celery logs to a file, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58024271/19300652

Answer (score 0):

I did this once using these general steps (there will be reading involved):

1. Configure a Python logger that writes to both stdout *and* a local log file.
2. Implement an endpoint that takes from/to date query parameters and reads the log file using something like journald, passing in the datetimes from the query parameters to get logs in the specified time range. The endpoint returns the logs in the response.
3. The frontend renders the returned logs.

I'm afraid there's no ready-made solution that I'm aware of.